# Change real process name in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux, process

I'm currently trying to change the process name of a process so I can read the more easily with htop, top, .... I want to `LD_PRELOAD` this code into another process so it gets renamed by an environemt variable.

I found a lot of stuff in the internet, but nothing works:

```
prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "Test");
```

This does not work because htop is not honoring the name.

Nginx `setproctitle` ([Link](http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/os/unix/ngx_setproctitle.c)) doesn't work as well, because it strips the parameters (which are needed by the process).

I tried everything I found and now I'm out of ideas.

Is this even possible in linux? And how?

Comment: Do you definitely need to solve this using C code?

Comment: I'd use any other language if it can produce .so files that can be preloaded.

Comment: So the original problem is how to change the name of a process? And the first solution is writing a .so LD_PRELOAD to achieve this? If I understand your systemd setup correctly, there may be a simpler solution that doesn't require either the .so or LD_PRELOAD in the first place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just run your program by shell script or your program through `exec` and pass desired name as `argv[0]`:

```
#/bin/bash
exec -a fancy_name a.out ...
```

or C/C++:

```
execl( "./a.out", "fancy_name", ... );
```

Comment: The question is about `c++` and not `bash` or running.

Comment: True, but it feels like an X-Y problem. Let's ask!

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I believe OP wants to solve this by C because he does not know that there is simpler solution with shell. Anyway it is done very similar by C/C++ code, I added that sample.

Comment: The problem is that all my services are called by systemd. If I overwrite the unit file, it gets rewritten with every package upgrade. So I want to define two environement variables (`LD_PRELOAD` and the title variable) through a systemd environemnt file which is not changed when upgrading.

Comment: @das_j create a copy of unit file and call it through systemd rather the one that deployed by package

Comment: @Slava hardly.  Try `( exec sleep hurz 120; )` vs. `( exec -a hurz sleep 120; )` and look for the process with e.g. `ps aux|grep hurz`.

Comment: @Slava, I could not reproduce your example. I need to give my process a unique name like fancy_name. Please tell me how to do this with a simple complete example. Thank you.

Comment: Under top it still shows the actual process name and not the fancy_name

Comment: This changes the command line, not the _process name_ (try ps -o comm,command, system monitor, htop with column COMM, etc)

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define NEW_NAME "hello_world"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if(strcmp(argv[0], NEW_NAME)) {
    argv[0] = NEW_NAME;
    execv("/proc/self/exe", argv);
    fputs("exec failed", stderr); 
    return 1;
  }
  while(1) // so it goes to the top
    ;
}
```